# How to properly create DOM elements using IO monads?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

I'm trying to write a javascript code that generates DOM elements, but in a functional way, because all functions generate side effects and mutations. To achieve this, I'm using the IO monad, but I think I still don't know how to use them very well...

First of all, I'm using the crocks library, which provides lots of ADTs to work with functional JS (I know there's ramda but they do not offer monads). Also, I'm using a little module which allows me to declare DOM elements using composition. (https://github.com/queckezz/elementx)

```
import IO from 'crocks/IO';
const { div, a, h1, h2, ul, li, button } = require('elementx');

const createHeader = div(
  h1(
    {class: 'title'},
    'This is a title'
  ),
  h2(
    {class: 'subtitle'}, 
    'This is a subtitle'
  ),
  div(
    {class: 'link'},
    a(
      {href: 'http://github.com'},
      'Github'
    )
  )
);

document.body.appendChild(createHeader);
```

The code above works, but it's obviously impure. I left the IO imported but I'm not using it because I don't know how to implement without breaking the code. I know an IO must receive a function as an argument, and then it returns IO(f(x)), but I'm quite lost as to how to implement it to both createHeader variable and appendChild. Besides, with an IO, the createHeader variable returns a function when I run it, but the appendChild expects a Node Object.

Comment: "but it's obviously impure" why?

Comment: `IO` in the context of the DOM just means deferring the impure computation with thunks (functions without arguments). Now you essentially want two things: You want to sequence impure computations by discarding the return value of the first one. And you want to chain impure computations by depending on the return value of the first one. That's pretty much it.

Comment: @JonasWilms `appendChild`??!?

Comment: Please not that creating DOM elements/subtrees isn't impure but appending them to the browser's DOM is.

Comment: So I don't realy need to wrap the createHeader in an IO since it doesn't mutate the DOM directly? That might make things easier...I'll make some tests here with what you said in mind, but more feedback and tips are always appreciated!

Comment: I once wrote a blog post [Taming the DOM](https://medium.com/@iquardt/taming-the-dom-50c8f1a6e892) that uses functional programming patterns intensively, in case you're interested. I am not a front end developer though.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so I solved the problem, the main issue was that...I was treating a function that produced no side-effects (createHeader would do nothing if not appended to the DOM) as impure. Sigh...newbie me.

The only impure part was the append, as said by bob in the comments.

So my solution was the following:

```
//append might not be a good name for this action but...
const append = nodeObj => IO(() => {
  document.body.appendChild(nodeObj);
})

append(createHeader)
  .run();
```

Which only creates the DOM elements once the IO is "activated", thus deferring the side-efects. Hope this helps other newbie functional programmers out there!

Comment: Of course, `run()` is still impure :-) The only benefit of this code is making it more obvious where the impurity lies.

Comment: @Bergi ...and to separate the pure from the impure portion of the program, so that reasoning about the former is easier - at least when you're used to algebraic code.

Comment: I'd argue that the impure `document.body.appendChild(createHeader);` part was already separated well from the pure `createHeader` construction :-)